# How to select one or all values in where clause

Tags: db2

I have a table with:

```
Col1    Col2  
123     I   
125     A    
126  
127     I      
128     A
```

I want to select all the records if no values is passed in where clause.
Seems like below script does not work

```
Select * from Table where Col2 coalesce('A', ' ')
```

Comment: What type of script? Why don't you check for the value in the script and compose the WHERE clause accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

I see two options

**1. Dynamic SQL**

You can use Dynamic SQL to assemble the query on the fly according to the parameter value. How to use Dynamic SQL depends on the specific programming language, ORM, or scripting you use. For example, when using MyBatis you would do:

```
<select>
  select * from mytable
  <if test="param != null">
    where col2 = #{param}
  </if>
</select>
```

The `<if>` tag will include or exclude the whole `WHERE` clause according the to runtime value of the parameter.

**2. Using SQL logic**

You can write your SQL `SELECT` as:

```
select * 
from mytable
where #{param} is null or col2 = #{param}
```

If the parameter is null, all rows of the table will be retrieved; if it's not null then only the matching rows will be retrieved.

Note: `#{param}` denotes the placeholder for your parameter. Change according to your programming language.